# While-loop prints wrong value but also kind of correct

Tags: python, loops

my code looks like this, I know the reason why its printing the way it is is because its "pin" is printing 3 times until "tries" = 3 . When the wrong pin is inputed it says please try again like it should but when the correct pin is entered it does what i described above.

```
correct_Pin = "4349"
tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    pin = input("HELLO, PLEASE ENTER YOUR BANK 4-DIGIT PIN: ")
    tries += 1
    if correct_Pin == pin:
        print("Correct | Welcome, please choose a selection")
        print(
            '''
    1. View balance. 
    ***********************************
    2. Withdraw.
    ************************************
    3. Make deposit
    ***********************************
    4. .
    ***********************************
            '''
        )
    if pin != correct_Pin:
        print("Please try again")
        if tries > 3 and correct_Pin != pin:
            break
```

When i move the pin outside of the while loop i get "Please try again" printed 3 times then the program breaks.

Im sure what im doing wrong is very simple. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The problem with your code is that you don't even break out of the loop even if you do enter the correct pin.   Shouldn't there be a break within the ```if correct_pin == pin:``` condition block?  Also, the ```if pin != correct_Pin:``` doesn't need to be there.  It could just as well be an ```else:```.

Comment: @ewokx if the correct pin is entered in needs to go into another condition, which is the multiline print. I tried what you said and while it does solve the issue of the pin showing up it does not keep open the input for a decision. Would i need to declare a variable for that value to be stored in?

Answer (score 0):

You should `break` the loop `if correct_Pin == pin`.

```
correct_Pin = "4349"
tries = 0
while tries < 3:
    pin = input("HELLO, PLEASE ENTER YOUR BANK 4-DIGIT PIN: ")
    tries += 1
    if correct_Pin == pin:
        print("Correct | Welcome, please choose a selection")
        print(
            '''
    1. View balance. 
    ***********************************
    2. Withdraw.
    ************************************
    3. Make deposit
    ***********************************
    4. .
    ***********************************
            '''
        )
        break  # <--- you should break the loop here
    if pin != correct_Pin:
        print("Please try again")
        if tries > 3 and correct_Pin != pin:
            break
```

Comment: if the correct pin is entered in needs to go into another condition, which is the multiline print. I tried what you said and while it does solve the issue of the pin showing up it does not keep open the input for a decision. Would i need to declare a variable for that value to be stored in?

Comment: Add the selection statement and any other actions above that `break` statement.